# Why Won't Some Code Work in Different Size Storyboards in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I am a low intermediate Xcode programmer. if I am not clear in something please bear with me and help me improve with feedback. Any feedback i am given, I will use to improve this question.

I am using Xcode 6

I am currently making an Iphone Game. I set it up as a single view application. My problem is making it work on different Size IPhones. At first, I did not know how to make Xcode pick the screens depending on which Iphone it is being played on, but I managed to make it work. My game is not using Auto Layout, it uses different storyboards in which the view controllers are different depending on the storyboard. For example: MainIphone6.Storyboard will have Iphone 6 view controllers.

My game consists of tapping image views (they do have tap gesture recognizers), after they are tapped the image view will pick a random point on the screen and move to it. the point has boundaries which I set so it will not go to places I don't want it to.

The first screen I made it work on was Iphone 5. It works perfectly. The second screen I made it work on was Iphone 4, the boundaries for the random positions are a little off do to the fact that it was originally programmed for iPhone 5, but I know how to fix this, that is not the problem.

The problem is that in my storyboards for Iphone 6 and 6 Plus, when the Image View is tapped, it doesn't move to the random point. This works on Iphone 5 and 4, but not on 6 and 6 plus.

Why doesn't my code work for this Storyboard, but it works on other storyboards, while it is the same code for all?

Note: I have speculated that it may be related to the linking of view controllers within story boards, because on iPhone 5 and 4 i can link with the modal segue, but in 6 and 6 plus, it says it is deprecated. I only mention this if it might help...

Comment: Making an app work with all screen sizes would be easier if you use auto layout. It's a powerful system that takes some time to learn, but it's with the effort. That being said, what does happen when you tap an image in the iPhone 6 simulator? Nothing?

Comment: When I tap it, it does not register my tap. it should move the image view to a random location. any suggestions?       would you mind showing me a please with good tutorials on this? Also, would auto layout work with this kind of game? any kind of application? @rdelmar

Comment: Without seeing ay code or knowing what you did in interface builder, I can't answer your questions. If it doesn't respond to a tap, you probably haven't added the gesture recognizer, or set the userInteractionEnabled to YES for the image view. Yes, auto layout would work fine for this type of game, or almost any app.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It turns out that I made a mistake creating the storyboards. I believe I did not add the gesture recognizers properly. @rdelmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from just your description. Deprecated code will still work so I doubt it is that. Did you try changing you code so that the 6 and 6 plus used the working 5 Storyboard. If it does the 6 storyboard has a problem. In this case, kill the 6 Storyboards,  duplicate the 5 Storyboard and modify it. Sounds like you may have been recreating each Storyboard anyway. In this situation I select the Storyboard in the Navigator and choose Duplicate from the File menu. This will save you some work and help guarantee that you do not make a mistake recreating all aspects of the Storyboard.

Also even if you do not want to use Autolayout, I would still use a single Storyboard and make the calculations in code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which storyboard do you refer to, 3.5,4.0,4.7,5.5, or the resizable storyboard which is like a square?  thank you for your feedback and suggestions.